# Vim: alter selection semantics for "I-beam" cursor

Tags: vim

Some concepts in text editing rely on the concept of "character under the cursor". However, if your cursor is a vertical bar or I-beam, these concepts aren't visually intuitive; the character under the cursor is in fact the one just to the right of the I-beam.

When a visual selection is being made in Vim, it always includes the "character under the cursor", and so can never be empty. When the user presses V, a selection containing just the character under the cursor is initiated. If the cursor is then moved one character left or right from that position, the selection still contains the original character plus the one before or after it. No matter where you move the cursor, the selection cannot be empty.

When the cursor is an I-beam, this behavior isn't intuitive. The I-beam appears to be a marker between characters, not over (or under) a character. Ideally, the selection should be initially empty, and the cursor position should be noted as the starting point of the selection. Then as the I-beam cursor is moved, the selection should include the text between the starting position and the new one, spanning from one abstract between-characters position to the other. Whenever the two positions coincide, the selection should be empty.

To make things worse, Vim doesn't highlight the character to the right of the cursor in a selection, under the assumption that it is covered by a block cursor.

**Is there some way to switch the visual selection semantics in Vim to pair with the I-beam cursor style?**

Comment: I'm also convinced that the answer is not only no, but it would take at least a week to implement (for an expert programmer, initially not familiar with the Vim code base). Logic having to do with the selection logic is scattered across multiple functions and source files, involving an unholy combination of global, buffer and window-specific variables.